# T-Sql Query with dynamic (unknown) number of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot-table

We have a project where we should provide the possible to the user to add own custom columns to various tables.

Edit: these are 2 tables, not one.

```
**Products**
ProductId
Name
Price
Date
UserId

**ProductsCustomColumns**
ProductId
ColumnName
ColumnValue
```

EDIT: Please note that the dynamic columns are recorded as values and we don't know the count of these...it can be 0 or 200 or any.

Here is an example:
[image]
Now when we query the products tables we want to show all the predefined columns and after them all custom columns.
Obviously each user can have own number of columns with values and names.

```
SELECT *, (and the custom columns) FROM Products WHERE UserId = 3 AND ProductId = 1
```

Here are 2 questions:

1. Would that be good solution from performance point of view or there is better approach for solving the dynamic columns requirement?
2. How can I create a query that could read all records from `ProductsCustomColumns` for given `userId` and `productId` and append the records as columns to the query?

Thanks.

Comment: Is ProductsCustomColumns a separate table?

Comment: Yes, separate table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write dynamic Query

```
DECLARE @COLUMNS VARCHAR(MAX)='', @QRY VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT  @COLUMNS = @COLUMNS +COLUMN_NAME +',' FROM 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='Products'

SELECT @COLUMNS =SUBSTRING (@COLUMNS,1 ,LEN(@COLUMNS)-1)

SELECT @QRY ='SELECT '+@COLUMNS + ' FROM Products WHERE UserId = 3 AND ProductId = 1' 
EXEC (@QRY)
```

**EDIT:** From your Comments & Edited Question

Schema I assumed from your Question

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
ProductId INT,
Name VARCHAR(250),
Price DECIMAL(18,2),
DateS DATETIME,
UserId INT)

INSERT INTO Products
SELECT 1,'Oil Product', 2000, GETDATE(), 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Amway', 600, GETDATE(), 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Thermal', 5000, GETDATE(), 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'Oil Product', 500, GETDATE(), 4



CREATE TABLE ProductsCustomColumns
(
ProductId INT ,
ColumnName VARCHAR(200),
ColumnValue VARCHAR(15))

INSERT INTO ProductsCustomColumns
SELECT 1, 'Licence_No', '1545'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Location ', 'Atlanta'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Qty ', '5'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Gross', '80000'
```

Now your Dynamic Code goes here

```
DECLARE  @COLUMN_PCC VARCHAR(MAX)='',  @PRODUCT_ID INT=1,@USER_ID INT=3, @QRY VARCHAR(MAX) ;

--preparing Custom Column Name List with comma ','
SELECT @COLUMN_PCC = @COLUMN_PCC+ [COLUMNNAME]  +',' FROM ProductsCustomColumns 
WHERE ProductId= @PRODUCT_ID
SELECT @COLUMN_PCC =SUBSTRING(@COLUMN_PCC,1,LEN(@COLUMN_PCC)-1)


--Preparing Dynamic Query
SELECT @QRY =' SELECT P.*, AV.* FROM Products P
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM ProductsCustomColumns WHERE ProductId= '+CAST(@PRODUCT_ID AS VARCHAR(50))+'
)
AS A
PIVOT 
(
MAX (COLUMNVALUE)
FOR [COLUMNNAME] IN ('+@COLUMN_PCC +')
)AS PVT
)AS AV ON P.ProductId= AV.ProductId 
AND P.UserId='++CAST(@USER_ID AS VARCHAR(50))+'
'

EXEC ( @QRY)
```

And the Result will be

```
 +-----------+-------------+---------+-------------------------+--------+-----------+------------+----------+
| ProductId |    Name     |  Price  |          DateS          | UserId | ProductId | Licence_No | Location |
+-----------+-------------+---------+-------------------------+--------+-----------+------------+----------+
|         1 | Oil Product | 2000.00 | 2016-12-09 18:06:24.090 |      3 |         1 |       1545 | Atlanta  |
+-----------+-------------+---------+-------------------------+--------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: The dynamic columns do not come from another table columns, they are records in the second table.

Comment: Looks amazing, let me give it a try!

Comment: Your solution works. Could you just tell me - I am getting an error at this line: FOR [COLUMNNAME] IN ('+@COLUMN_PCC +')
Error message: Incorrect syntax near 'Value'.
What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Replacce `EXEC ( @QRY)` with `Select @QRY` and check what syntax it is missing for your data.

Comment: Ah, yes, one of my values had space in it, so I had to remove the space. Instead of Custom Column it became CustomColumn and it works. :)

Comment: Now I am adding new records to the ProductsCustomColumns table and they automatically appear when I run the query. This was exactly what I needed. Many thanks again and all the best, Shakeer!

Answer (score 1):

You need dynamic sql no other way to do this

```
DECLARE @sql      VARCHAR(max),
        @cust_col VARCHAR(max)

SET @cust_col = (SELECT Quotename(CustomColumns) + ','
                 FROM   ProductsCustomColumns
                 FOR xml path(''))

SELECT @cust_col = LEFT(@cust_col, Len(@cust_col) - 1)

SET @sql = 'SELECT *, ' + @cust_col + ' FROM Products WHERE UserId = 3 AND ProductId = 1'

EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: When I run it, it shows error: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Comment1'. 
Note: Comment1 is the value in the CustomColumn.

Answer (score 1):

In general it is a very bad idea to add custom data in additional columns of your main table. Just imagine 100 customers using this. All of them have differing table schemas and you wnat to write an update script for all of them?

It is a pain in the neck, if you have to deal with result sets where you don't know the structure in advance!

You have several choices:

- Add one column of type `XML`. The advantage: The resultset is fix. You just need a customer specific rule, how to interpret the XML. You can solve this with an *inline table valued function*. Pass in the XML and get a derived table back. Call this with `CROSS APPLY` and you are out...
- Add a new table with the customerID and Key-Value-Pairs
- If the additional data is not completely different, add some of the columns to your main table as `SPARSE` columns

Comment: Actually these are 2 tables.

Comment: And also we were thinking about the predefined, large amount of columns...